# Problem with package listlbls and report class

Tags: cross-referencing, report

I'm getting an error with package `listlbls`: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listlbls?lang=en. It prints a list of labels used in the document. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listlbls}

\begin{document}
\listoflabels
\chapter{Second}\label{ch:ghost}
\section{A section}\label{sec:first}
Some text anf a reference \ref{ch:ghost}.
\section{Another Section}\label{sec:another}
Some more text and and another reference \ref{sec:first}.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:triv}
1=1
\end{equation}
By equation \ref{eq:triv}  section \ref{sec:another}.
\end{document}
```

When I use it together with the report class I get an error:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listlbls/listlbls.sty:55:
LaTeX Error:
Missing \begin{document}.
l.55 \ifdefined\chapter*
```

So it seems to be something to do with the chapter command as it works fine in the article class. Most puzzlingly one of the online compilers I tested it on returned and error *and* gave an output with a empty first page bar one `*` character! Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug in `listlbls.sty`. You can solve it by making a private copy of that file in your working directory and changing the line (line number 55)

```
\ifdefined\chapter*
```

to

```
\ifdefined\chapter
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your fix and it worked, although I am still puzzled as to why that line was in the package originally, as it seems like it was testing for a report or book class anyway...